# how to pass customer id(value) ,name(label) as options to multiselect field

Tags: customer, collection, multiselect-attribute

I have client requirement like this.I need to get all customers in multiselect field.
and I'm writing following code

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false){
    if (is_null($this->_options)) {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
               ->addNameToSelect();

        $this->_options = $collection->toOptionArray();

        }
        return $this->_options;

    }
```

and its giving only names as option labels in `multi-select` field. But option value fields are empty.

And extra functions are,

```
public function getOptionsArray($withEmpty = true) {
        $options = array();

        foreach ($this->getAllOptions($withEmpty) as $option) {

        $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
    }
    return $options;
}
/**
 * get option text
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return string
 * @author Ultimate Module Creator
 */
public function getOptionText($value) {
    $options = $this->getOptionsArray();
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        $value = array($value);
    }
    $texts = array();
    foreach ($value as $v) {
        if (isset($options[$v])) {
            $texts[] = $options[$v];
        }
    }
    return implode(', ', $texts);
}
```

Comment: Ha...you are using the ultimate module creator...nice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, It's working fine.

```
    public function toOptionArray()
    {

        $text = "";
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

        $ids = $customer->getCollection()->getAllIds();

        $i = 0;
        if ($ids)
        {   
             foreach ($ids as $id)
            {
                 $cat = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
                 $cat->load($id); 
                 $s = $cat->getName();
                 $text[$i] = array('value'=>$cat->getID(), 'label'=>Mage::helper('YourModule')->__($cat->getName()));
                 $i++;
            }
        } 
         return $text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

following is an example what i have used in my project, in this i just return the strore name to select

hope it will help you.....

```
 static function getOptionValues($inlcudeNone = false)
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->getCollection()
        ->addFilter('website_id', 2);
        $values = array();
        if (!isset($collection)) {
            $values[] = array('label' => "--None--", 'value' => 0);
        }
        foreach ($collection as $store) {
            $values[] = array('label' => $store->getName(), 'value' => $store->getId());
        }
        return $values;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solve it like this.. (Magento 1.9)

```
public function getAllOptions(){

    $customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $ids = $customers->getCollection()->getAllIds();

    if ($ids)
    {    
      foreach ($ids as $id) 
      {    
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->load($id); 

        $options[] = array(
          'value' => $customer->getID(),
          'label' => $customer->getName()
        );
      }    
    }    

    $this->_options = $options;

    return $this->_options;
  }
```

Comment: you should not use load in a loop. It's a real performance killer.

Comment: thanks @Marius then can you suggest and alternative?

Comment: get the ids and names directly from the collection.